# How to recode integers to other values in python?

Tags: python, recode

I was surprised this question has not been asked yet. Given an array of integers

```
x = np.random.randint(1,4,10)

> array([3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1])
```

How can I (easily) change all values according to some systematic rule, such as

```
x[x==1] = 5
x[x==2] = 6
x[x==3] = 7

> array([6, 5, 6, 7, 5, 5, 6, 5, 7, 6])
```

The rule may be more complex than this, e.g. recode `1=2` and `2=1` so that the order plays a role.

Comment: This is a great application for using a dictionary as a direct look-up list.  Or, if the transfer function is this simple, then you simply apply the rule of `item += 4` on the entire list.

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward way would just be to iterate over the array replacing values.

```
rule = {1: 5, 2: 6, 3: 7}
x = x.vectorize(lambda x: rule[x] if x in rule else x)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `map` to do the transformation. `map` takes a transformation function and a list of inputs and outputs the result of applying that function to all of the inputs systematically.

For example:

```
def mapping(i):
    if i == 1:
        return 5
    elif i == 2:
        return 6
    elif i == 3:
        return 7
    return i

print array(map(mapping, [3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

While others may suggest *just* using a dictionary, I would suggest using something that is actually made for this particular type of behavior rather manually using a dictionary, [Python's `map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) function.

`map` takes a function and applies it to each input, and returns the result of that as a list.  So you would create your `if x == y, return z` as a function and apply `map(yourfunction, yourlist)` to it.

The nice [thing about `map`](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html) is that you can use it on any iterable, and not just your list

Normal python version

```
def numberfunc(x):
    if x == 1:
       return 5

    elif x == 2:
       return 6

    elif x== 3:
       return 7

    else:
        return x

x = [random.randint(1,4) for _ in range(10)]
# array([3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1])

x = map(numberfunc, x)
# array([6, 5, 6, 7, 5, 5, 6, 5, 7, 6])
```

Numpy version (numpy uses [`vectorize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) as its `map`)

```
x = np.random.randint(1,4,10)
# array([3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1])

x = x.vectorize(numberfunc)
# array([6, 5, 6, 7, 5, 5, 6, 5, 7, 6])
```

Additionally if your number map function had a large amount of comparisons (larger than the 3 you list here) you might consider using python's [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) in order to increase performance given [O(1) armortized](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) element access times, for example:

```
num_dict {1:5, 2:6, 3:7, ...}
def numberfunc(x):
        if x in num_dict:
            return num_dict[x]
        return x
```

You probably wouldn't want to do this in the simple case because of the *armortized* gotcha on dictionary run time performance and constant overhead.  [Amortized](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/amortize) basically means that taking into account all operations you will make that are armortized, the cost of the most expensive operations will be offset by the *cheap*ness of the less expensive ones.  Occasionally dictionary mutation can be expensive; taken as a whole, many dictionary mutations will not be expensive compared to other data structures. Dictionaries also have larger indexing overheads compared to things like arrays.  In a naive implementation, [you will typically have to iterate over lists given your key to find your value](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/hash_data_structure.htm) and in more complicated scenarios, [often more guaranteed overhead is involved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuckoo_hashing)